# One Plus Nord - MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT - not working., Unable to set the time limit

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-camera, android-native-library

MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT not working

`val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE) takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 30) takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, ACTIVITY_RESULT_REQUEST_CODE_FOR_CAMERA)`

it's working other phones not working in one plus nord(oxygen os 11.0.1.1.EB13DA)

takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 30)